# Existence of a Surjective Linear Map $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Is it possible for there to be a surjective linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^4$?

I feel like this isn't possible because $\mathbb{R}^3$ has fewer vectors than $\mathbb{R}^4$. If so, linear transformations between the two spaces should be injective. But if that's the case, for all linear transformations $\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^4$, the kernel should only ever contain the zero vector. But this is not the case. Why?

Comment: $\mathbb R^3$ is spanned by $3$ vectors. Their images under a linear transformation $T$ span the image of $T$.

Comment: Remark: $\Bbb R^3$ does not have fewer vectors than $\Bbb R^4$. It's the same amount, actually.

Comment: If the question at the end is why the kernel might contain more than the zero vector, and thus why the mapping need not be injective, I think I've given an answer that's simpler than most here.  It was inexplicably down-voted. So @also, do you have some objection to my answer?

Answer (score 4):

There are functions from $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R^4$ which are surjective, but none of them preserve the vector space structures. By the rank-nullity formula: $$3 = \dim \ker T + \dim {\rm Im } \ T,$$ so we can't have $\dim {\rm Im } \ T = 4 $.

Answer (score 3):

No. In $\mathbb R^4$ there are linearly independent sets of $4$ vectors. This is a problem, since if $f$ is a linear map and $S$ is a set of vectors, then we can prove:

> If $f[S]$ is linearly independent, then $S$ is.

which is easy to do by looking at the contrapositive that if $S$ is dependent than so is $f[S]$, which is obvious since if $\alpha_1 s_1 +\alpha_2 s_2 +\ldots+ \alpha_n s_n=0$, then so $f(\alpha_1 s_1 +\alpha_2 s_2 +\ldots +\alpha_n s_n)=0$, but we can expand the left hand side to
$$\alpha_1f(s_1)+\alpha_2f(s_2)+\ldots+\alpha_n f(s_n)=0$$
implying a dependency in $f[S]$.

If $f:\mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^4$ were surjective, then we could take some set $V$ of $4$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb R^4$ and find some set of four vectors $S$ in $\mathbb R^3$ such that $f[S]=V$. However, this is impossible, since it would mean that the vectors of $S$ are linearly independent, but this can't happen in $\mathbb R^3$, which has dimension $3$.

Answer (score 2):

No, the dimension of the range of such a linear transformation is at most $3$, by the rank-nullity theorem.

Answer (score 2):

A linear function whose domain is $\mathbb R^3$ is determined by its values at a basis of $\mathbb R^3$, which contains just three vectors.  The image of a linear map from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R^4$ is the span of a set of three vectors in $\mathbb R^4$, and the span of only three vectors is less than all of $\mathbb R^4$.

However, that is no reason why the map should be injective.  The three vectors in $\mathbb R^4$ that are the images of the aforementioned basis vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ need not be linearly independent.  If they are linearly independent, then the map is injective; otherwise it is not.

Comment: Is there a reason for the down-vote here?

Comment: Possibly the down-voter is not impressed by your lack of mentioning dimension - a concept that explains why the span of three vectors is less than all of $\Bbb{R}^4$. I'm sure you know this, but someone new to linear algebra may need to have this step explained.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : But it appears from the question that the poster is aware of that. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: That's not the impression I got. He uses the phrase "... has fewer vectors than..." He is unfamiliar with the concept of dimension or cardinality, because he doesn't specify which he means. But, it is kinda pointless for me to speculate what a down-voter had in mind. It is not an extreme view to take IMO.

Comment: It is precisely that remark that makes it appear that he's aware of the relevant concept.  His imprecision in use of language is hardly surprising.

Comment: I disagree. No one fully conversant with these concepts would need to ask this question.

Comment: Indeed, no one fully conversant with these concepts would ask this question or write the way he did; nor would anyone whose grasp of these concepts is not quite deficient.  But he seemed clearly aware that three vectors are not enough to span $\mathbb R^4$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score -2):

They have the same cardinality but I don't believe cardinality implies existence of surjective linear transformation.

Comment: Cardinality is how we compare the size of sets with no additional structure. However, here we have sets with extra structure (i.e. addition and scalar multiplication), so we no longer talk about bijections, as in cardinality, we talk about bijective linear maps - so cardinality is more or less irrelevant (and, in this sense, is actually replaced by dimension)